# Ограничение подключений OpenVPN

Tags: openvpn

Есть OpenVPN сервер на debian.

Можно ли ограничить сервер так, чтобы на 1 сертификат мог подключиться только 1 человек одновременно? Т.е., чтобы нельзя было распространить ovpn файл, чтобы с него не сидело 100 человек.

Comment: это же поведение по умолчанию. если у вас иначе, значит вы используете [опцию `duplicate-cn`](https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/Openvpn23ManPage)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Можно ли ограничить сервер так что бы на 1 сертификат мог подключиться только 1 человек одновременно?

да, можно. точнее, можно (при необходимости) **отключить** это **умолчальное** поведение при помощи [опции `duplicate-cn`](https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/Openvpn23ManPage):

> Allow multiple clients with the same common name to concurrently connect. In the absence of this option, OpenVPN will disconnect a client instance upon connection of a new client having the same common name.

мой вольный перевод:

> позволяет нескольким клиентам с одним *common name* подключиться одновременно. в отсутствие этой опции при подключении нового клиента с тем же самым *common name* «старый» будет отключен.